# "hit my head in short"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard of the phrase "hit my head in short" on an American radio. I figure it probably means *put/make/explain it in short*. But I'm really not sure. I searched it on the web, and I haven't found it used anywhere. Is it a common phrase? Or we should take it literally.

Note: I might mishear it. It could "*heat my head in short*" as well.

Comment: Can you give any indication as to the context in which it was said?

Comment: @ChrisMack It goes fast and I haven't caught much. But I think that person was trying to be brief. That's why I think he meant "put it in short".

Comment: @ChrisMack I might mishear. It could be "heat my head in short".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person was trying to be brief, then saying "in short" is a very idiomatic way to state this as their intention. It's often said before, or perhaps after, providing a summary or simplification of something you've already said in a longer way.

Consider the following sentence uttered by *Mr. Micawber* in Charles Dickens' *David Copperfield* (the character is renowned for his use of "in short"):

> Accidents will occur in the best regulated families; and in families not regulated by **that pervading *influence* which sanctifies while it enhances** the–a–I would say, *in short*, by **the *influence* of Woman**, in the lofty character of Wife, they may be expected with confidence, and must be borne with philosophy.

This may well be what you are hearing.

Comment: I know the phrase "in short", but not "hit my head in short".

Comment: The phrase "hit my head in short", I've never heard, so would need the surrounding context. If it is a common saying, I imagine it's very colloquial!